How to iterate un-unamed helm value.yaml files which has array of objects?
I have a helm template and values.yaml file and want to iterate all the objects of helm values in helm template.
#values.yaml
--------------
- ns: "test-ns"
  app: "test-app"
- ns: "test-ns"
  app: "test-app-2"

#helm template
---------------
{{- range $index, $app := . }}
    namespace: {{ $app.ns }}
    application: {{ $app.app }}
{{- end }}


I couldnt able to iterate over the array of objects, I am getting this error:
error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type lib.ValuesObj


I'm guessing helm template . produces that error?  Does helm template --debug . look right visually?  What's around that template fragment; what output do you expect it to produce?  (I'd consider running helm install multiple times, if you just need multiple copies of the application in multiple namespaces.)

The values object is of type map[string] and will fail when the yaml is an array.
You could change your values.yaml as follows:
details:
- ns: "test-ns"
  app: "test-app"
- ns: "test-ns"
  app: "test-app-2"

i.e. putting the array elements inside the details field.
And then on your helm template use it like so:
{{- range $index, $app := .Values.details }}
    namespace: {{ $app.ns }}
    application: {{ $app.app }}
{{- end }}

Obviously, I don't know exactly what you are trying to create (maybe extra tweaking might be needed on your part) but this way you'll be able to do your loop.
